# Add one letter to a textView

Tags: java, android, button, textview, calculator

I'd like to code a little calculator. I'm new to Android Programming and I want to know how to add one letter into a TextView. The letter should be put in after i clicked a Button (tried it with onClickListener).

Comment: please read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Sharing a link to simple calculator which will give you good understanding - https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2tpcnyywqmtybe/Calculator.rar

Comment: `texView.append("a");` will works for you.. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
          char letter='a';
          t.setText(t.getText()+letter);
}
```

where t is an object of `TextView`.

`setText` allows you to reset text at runtime

`getText` gets current text of `TextView`

Answer (score 2):

First, get the text in the textview:

```
 String input = textview.getText().toString();
```

Then, append some input:

```
input += " 26";
```

Then, reset the textview with the current input

```
textview.setText(input);
```

Just declare this textview as a class level variable

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'c';
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        text.setText(text.getText()+'c');
    }
}
```

Just think from this.

Answer (score 1):

Get the text from the TextView:

```
String text = textview.getText().toString();
```

Add your one letter to the end of the `text`:

```
String newText = StringBuilder(text).append("x").toString().
```

*(`x` being your letter)*

Pass the `newText` to your `TextView`:

```
textview.setText(newText);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

TextView allows to set a CharSequence as content so StringBuilder could be used. It is easy and efficient to append a char to StringBuilder.

StringBuilder does not have a hook to register a listener, however, so TextView definitely will not be updated after you append your character. Maybe invalidate() or setText(same builder) could refresh the TextView? Anybody wants to try?